# crystal report - linking subreport parameters

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to add a subreport and pass the parameters from my main report to the subreport.  When I link everything up the subreport runs through thousands of records looking for insurance information on my test subject but there is no record.

If I go to a query tool and run the query with the WHERE clause that I expect to be added on the Crystal report query it takes milliseconds to return no rows.

When i run the preview in Crystal reports it takes minutes to run through all the records.  Why doesn't the query return no records like it should? Or just the one specific one I am looking for if there is a record?  I don't want all 10,000+ records returned to crystal just the ONE or ZERO that I should get based on the parameters I am passing from the main report!!

Thanks for any guidance,
Leslie

Edit:  I have a query on the main report that needs PatID and Episode_Number.  I have a query on my subreport that I would like to filter on the SAME PatID and Episode_Number.  The sub-report query is:

`select b.patid, b.episode_number, b.guarantor_name, Trim(b.guar_address_line1|| ' ' || ifNull(b.guar_address_line2, '')) address, b.guar_address_city || ', ' || b.guar_address_state || ' ' || b.guar_address_zip location,
b.guar_phone_number
from billing_guar_data b`

I have not added any "extra" parameters onto this Command.
I have these parameters that have been added by this linking:
  `Pm-Command.PATID    and    Pm-Command.Episode_Number`

which I picked from the Linking page when I created the sub-report

Comment: Have you got parameters in the subreport? Have you linked them to the main report? Are the parameters actually used in the "where clause" of the subreport?

Comment: I have tried to do this...I have parameters on the sub-report but I didn't put them there...they appeared after I did the linking.

Comment: It shouldn't be this hard.  I want to use the same parameters on all the queries in my report. I want to select one person and one episode and have all the data I need. I want the selected/entered PatID and Episode_Number passed through to every query I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this before.  Took me a while to figure out how to get parameters into an SQL command within a subreport.  It's true, the SQL you have there will fetch all the records because there is no **where** clause.  If you are passing your parameters to get it in the **Select Expert**, you are filtering after you've retrieved the 10,000+ records.  From the main report, the parameter has to get into the SQL command of the subreport in order for it to retrieve the specific record.  Here's how to do it.

You can pass either the oiginal parameter or the field (if available) from the main report.  Since your wrote "Pm-Command.PATID and Pm-Command.Episode_Number", you are passing the field.  First, add a **where** clause to your SQL command

```
select 
   b.patid, b.episode_number, b.guarantor_name, Trim(b.guar_address_line1|| ' ' || ifNull(b.guar_address_line2, '')) address, b.guar_address_city || ', ' || b.guar_address_state || ' ' || b.guar_address_zip location, b.guar_phone_number 
from
   billing_guar_data b
where
   b.patid = {?Pm-Command.PATID}
   and b.episode_number = {?Pm-Command.Episode_Number}
```

Next, in the same window on the side parameter list, create 2 parameter

- Pm-Command.PATID
- Pm-Command.Episode_Number

Then in the main report bring up the Change Subreport links...  The 2 parameters you are sending should still be there.  Make sure the "Select data in subreport based on field" is unchecked on both parameters.  If this is checked, it will send the parameter to the **Select Expert**.  Because it's going to be in the SQL Command, it should be unchecked.

Comment: The subreport's selection formula, or 'Select Expert', doesn't necessarily work that way. Crystal will automatically add the logic in the selection formula into the subreport's where-clause so there is usually no need to add a SQL-Command. This includes the logic in your example. The only time it would be necessary to create a SQL Command is if you were doing some processing on the columns as a part of the record selection, like using a string processing function.

Comment: True; if Crystal is used to build the SQL Query, the select Expert will act as the Where clause.  However, if an SQL-command is used, Crystal will run the query as is and while it's retrieving the records it will look for the records stated in the Select Expert.  Nothing stops anyone from using the select expert with an SQL Command.  It becomes a performance issue when the query is retrieving thousands of rows and it only needs 1.

SQL commands are useful when the job needs to be done on the server side. I could be wrong since the question never stated that it's a SQL command.

Comment: Yes, I AM using the SQL command and writing my own queries.  I will work on this some more today now that I am fresh and not frustrated and see if I can work through it.  I am using the Pm-Command fields only because those were the ones I picked...if it makes sense to pick other links instead I can do that.  The other thing that I have noticed is that if I re-run the report and select prompt for new parameters, I have to enter the paramters from the sub-reports.  Is that just because I am running it IN Crystal Reports and once I move it to the calling program that won't be an issue?

Comment: I figured it out!!!  Hooray!  In the linking section I selected the parameter from the main query and moved it to the box on the right and then in the left hand drop down I selected the sub-report parameter...now when I am prompted for parameters I only get the main report ones and my report runs super fast!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Crystal may not be using the WHERE-clause for the subreport that you think it is. This could be because you're using Crystal syntax or a Crystal function in the subreport's record selection formula that it can't translate into SQL. When this happens, it will fetch ALL the records from the DB and perform the record selection locally, which sounds like what is happening in your case.

To check the subreport's query, first preview the whole report, then open the subreport in its own tab in Crystal (This will open it like it's its own report in Crystal) then go to 'Database' -> 'Show SQL Query'.

If you post the selection criteria, that would help also.

Comment: Ok I can see in the sub-report 'Show Query' that there is NO where clause on it.  I have linked the sub-reports to the main report, the main report has the ONE person that the report is generated for...I guess I am doing the linking wrong....

Comment: this never shows the actual parameters used, just the "pre" query text that I have entered.

Comment: @Leslie Please post the subreport's record selection formula. It sounds like this is where it is breaking down.